# How to check if a variable is a number or a string?

Tags: ruby

How to check if a variable is a number or a string in Ruby?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

There are several ways:

```
>> 1.class #=> Fixnum
>> "foo".class #=> String
>> 1.is_a? Numeric #=> true
>> "foo".is_a? String #=> true
```

Comment: This doesn't check whether the *variable* is a number, it checks whether the object the variable *points to* is a number. There is a *huge* difference between the two.

Comment: Given how questions on SO (and elsewhere) are colloquially asked, it's fair to assume that's what OP meant, especially since he or she accepted it.

Answer (score 31):

```
class Object
  def is_number?
    to_f.to_s == to_s || to_i.to_s == to_s
  end
end

> 15.is_number?
=> true
> 15.0.is_number?
=> true
> '15'.is_number?
=> true
> '15.0'.is_number?
=> true
> 'String'.is_number?
=> false
```

Comment: This worked for me where `.is_a? Numeric` did not. I was checking if a field extracted from a CSV file was a number, thus comparison to `Numeric` fails because it is actually a string that also happens to be a number.

Comment: This fails in a few cases, like `15.10`, `015` or `15.33333333333333333`.

Comment: The following definition for is_number? satsifies Andrew's concerns:
    def is_number?(text)
      !!(/^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$/ =~ text)
    end

Answer (score 19):

```
var.is_a? String

var.is_a? Numeric
```

Comment: This doesn't check whether the *variable* is a number, it checks whether the object the variable *points to* is a number. There is a *huge* difference between the two.

Comment: @Jörg: I think it is pretty obvious what the OP is asking, there's no need for pedantry in this case.

Comment: @muistooshort well, not really. I came here looking for a way to _test_ a variable to check if it contained a string or a number value. So it's not pretty obvious to me, at least.

Answer (score 5):

The [`finishing_moves` gem](https://github.com/forgecrafted/finishing_moves) includes a [`String#numeric?`](https://github.com/forgecrafted/finishing_moves/wiki/String#stringnumeric) method to accomplish this very task. The approach is the same as installero's answer, just packaged up.

```
"1.2".numeric?
#=> true

"1.2e34".numeric?
#=> true

"1.2.3".numeric?
#=> false

"a".numeric?
#=> false
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class Object
  def numeric?
    Float(self) != nil rescue false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Print its class, it will show you which type of variable is (e.g. String or Number).

e.g.:

```
puts varName.class
```

Comment: This doesn't check whether the *variable* is a number, it checks whether the object the variable *points to* is a number. There is a *huge* difference between the two.

Answer (score -4):

```
if chr.to_i != 0
  puts "It is number,  yep"
end
```

Comment: What if `chr` is `"0"`?

Comment: Please add explanations to your answer.