# Check whether my variable is an Integer or String

Tags: ruby

I need to check whether my variable is an Integer or a String. 
The code below will just break the loop, without warning me for an illegal character. Can anyone help me to find the mistake?

```
x = 0
while x == 0        
  name = gets.chomp.capitalize 
  if name.empty?
    puts "No input. Try again"
  elsif name.is_a? Integer
    puts "Illegal character: Integer "
  else 
    x = 1 
  end               
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a variable is a number or a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616360/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-a-number-or-a-string)

Comment: Do you want to have your string completely without digits? A string like "asdfg09qwerty" would be valid to you or not?

Comment: `elsif name.is_a? Integer` will always return `false` because `name` is a string. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Because `gets` returns a string you need to find out if the string represents a number (and only a number).

First, translate your string to an integer with `to_i`. Please note that `to_i` returns `0` for strings that do not include numbers. In a second step check if translating this integer back into a string matches the original string

```
 string.to_i.to_s == string
```

Note that this is just a simple example, it wouldn't work for example with the string `00`.

Another way might be checking if the string only contains numbers. That could be done by using a regexp:

```
string.match(/\A\d+\z/)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
loop do
  puts "Enter name"
  name = gets.chomp
  if name.empty?
    puts "No input, try again"
  elsif name.scan(/\d+/).any?
    puts "Illegal character: Integer"
  else
    raise StopIteration
  end
end
```

#### case-expression

Or use a case-expression to tidy things up.

```
loop do
  puts "Enter name"
  case gets.chomp
  when ''
    puts "No input, try again"
  when /\d/
    puts "Illegal character: Integer"
  else
    raise StopIteration
  end
end
```

See [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/String.html#method-i-scan), [Array#any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Array.html#method-i-any-3F) and [StopIteration](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/StopIteration.html) for further details

Comment: `match` is preferable here to `scan`. See Spickermann's answer.

Comment: What's up with the two accounts? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I guess one was to remain anonymous and one was more 'public' with my real name. Never really used my anonymous one until a few days back when I thought I'd testdrive a new username iceツ. It certainly was not for any illicit reasons (0 votes cast). Anyhow, thought better of keeping both accounts and in the process of merging, but will keep this username for now:)

Comment: Oh no, I wasn't implying any shady activity on your part. Just being curious :)